# OpenStack's virtual nodes permanently in paused state

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, rdo

Recently I deployed Red Hat OpenStack 10 with Jenkins. I've found that my running nodes are became paused after a while.

`virsh list` stdout:

```
Id  | Name       | State
-------------------------
1    undercloud-0  paused
2    compute-0     paused
3    controller-0  paused
```

I tried to start or reboot VMs, but it didn't help. Machines are still in `paused` state. Is there any obvious things which I might miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found there is a lack of free space appeared after OpenStack runs for some time.

RHEL machines had smaller `/` partition and quite big `/home` partition. I found a VM images stored in `/var` and just moved it into `/home`

The steps are:

1. Stop all running VMs

   `# for i in $(virsh list --name); do virsh destroy $i; done`
2. Create new directory and move images there

   `# mkdir /home/_images`

   `# mv /var/lib/libvirt/images/* /home/_images`
3. Remove the old directory with images and create a symlink to the new directory.

   `# rmdir /var/lib/libvirt/images`

   `# ln -s /home/_images /var/lib/libvirt/images`
4. Start VMs again (or reboot the machine), an ideal order is 1. undercloud-0, 2. controller-0, 3. compute-x nodes

   `# for i in $(virsh list --name); do virsh reboot $i; done`